# nodemailer email not sent and no errors logged

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer to send email but it's not sending any email and the strange thing is that it's also not logging any error.

Here's the code of my route:

```
router.post("/form", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { name, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (!user) return res.status(501).send("Something went wrong");
    let token = await user.getSignedToken();
  

    try {
      user.emailToken = await user.verifyEmail();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
    

    try {
      await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
    
    const options = {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
    };

    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "myEmail",
        pass: "myPass",
      },
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      from: "myEmail",
      to: req.body.email,
      subject: "Verify Email Token",
      text: `go to the below link\nhttp://localhost:3000/verifyEmail/${emailToken}`,
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
    });
    
    res.cookie("token", token, options);
    res.send("Check email for activation");
  } catch (ex) {
    res.send(ex);
  }
});
```

So, it's not sending any email and after it, the res.cookie and the res.send line is also not working. But, the server is not logging any error/exceptions. So, what could be the issue? I used nodemailer in another route (with the same gmail account as this one) and it was working. So, what could be the problem that the code here isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mailoptions object, you are using **emailToken** and that variable is never defined. Instead, you might wanna use user.emailToken